# Angular-Foundation modal error

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-foundation

I have an Angular Js - Typescript project. I'm trying to develop a Modal with [Angular-Foundation](https://pineconellc.github.io/angular-foundation/), but it's not working.

This is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div>
   <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
   <h3>I'm a modal!</h3>
   <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in vm.items">
       <a ng-click="selected.item = item">{{ vm.item }}</a>
      </li>
   </ul>
   <p>Selected: <b>{{ selected.item }}</b></p>
   <button class="button secondary" ng-click="reposition()">Reset top     position</button>
   <a class="close-reveal-modal" ng-click="vm.cancelModal()">&#215;  </a>
   </script>

   <button class="button" ng-click="vm.openModal()">Open me!</button>
   <div ng-show="selected">Selection from a modal: {{ selected }}  </div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
public items: any[];
constructor(private $modal: any){
   this.items = ["item1", "item2", "item3"];
}
public openModal() {
        let modalInstance = this.$modal.open({
          templateUrl: "myModalContent.html",
          controller: "MissionsCtrl",
          resolve: {
            items: function () {
              return this.items;
            }
          }
        });
        modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
          this.selected = selectedItem;
        }, function () {
          console.log("Modal dismissed at:" + new Date());
      });
    }
```

And this is the error I get:
[image: Error]

**INFO:** I have the module "mm.foundation" included in app.ts, and JS files (mm-foundation.min.js and mm-foundation-tpls.min.js) correctly referenced in index.html.

Ultimately, someone knows how to implement a modal with AngularJS and Typescript without using angular-foundation?

I have no idea where the problem is.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

I add my app.ts file:

```
(function(){
"use strict";

angular.module("MyApp", [
    "ngSanitize",
    "pascalprecht.translate",
    "color.picker",
    "ui.router",
    "mm.foundation",

    "app.core",
]);
```

})();

Reading [Angular Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/ctreq?p0=tabset&p1=tabContentTransclude) I believe that the issue is in my controller, but I still didn't know how to solve it.

Comment: add you app.js file

Answer (score 0):

I got it!

The fault was in another part of the application, where I had created a navigation bar that used the tabset class of foundation , and was giving conflict with angular foundation.